# Noun for "receive"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

*Receipt?  Receiving?*

I'm trying to come up with a name for "the acceptance of a delivery."  I'd like to be able to say

> Ten deliveries were made but there are only five [fill_in_the_blank_here] on record.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's clearest to just leave it out. What's wrong with `Ten deliveries were made but there are only five on record`.

Comment: 1. Receiving is a gerund not a noun. 2. The question is open-ended and subjective.

Comment: @Kris That is incorrect, in that gerunds are indeed numbered amongst the nouns.

Comment: To add to tenfour's suggestion . . . ***"Ten deliveries were made but only five are documented."***

Comment: @KristinaLopez *documented* is not a noun.

Comment: @Kris, of course not. It's just part of a suggestion to phrase the example in a clearer way which is why it's a comment and not an answer. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Receipt* works.   As in, "receipt of the items has been acknowledged."

> Receipt \Re*ceipt"\ (r[-e]*s[=e]t"),
>   n. [OE. receite, OF.
>        recete, recepte, F. recette, fr. L. recipere, receptum, to
>        receive. See {Receive}.]
>        1. The act of receiving; reception. "At the receipt of your
>           letter." --Shak.
>           [1913 Webster]

Likely variations for your case would include

"Ten deliveries were made but there are only five *received items* on record."

"Ten deliveries were made but the records show only five items were received."

Comment: One gotcha with receipt is that it typical refers to an actual slip of paper that was used as a receipt. Other than that, it works. +1

Comment: I use this all the time.  For instance:  "Note:  Customer will pay upon receipt of product."

Comment: The noun form of *receive* is *receipt*.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is *Received*

as in

*Ten deliveries were made but according to our records only five were received*

Answer (score 1):

I think you said it already: "deliveries".

Answer (score 0):

*Receptions* could carry this meaning here,

> *noun*
>   **1** the action or process of receiving something sent, given , or inflicted

<sup>*~NOAD*</sup>

and deliveries are often received at a *reception desk*, or simply at *Receptions*.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can talk about reception of a signal but not an item. In this context, "reception" sounds like something a non-native speaker would say because they took "receive" and found a similar sounding noun. As you say, the reception is the place where things are received; it's not used for the acts of receiving that occur there.