# Is there a hypernym for "order confirmation", "quotation" and "invoice"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there an abstraction for the following three words?

- Order confirmation
- Quotation
- Invoice

I want to create a base class for them but I can't find a word that describes all three.

Comment: Is this English Language or Programming? Just call it a TransactionTracker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers English language. Just thought I'd be nice if I told what I'm going to use the synonym for.

Comment: With respect, you don't actually want a synonym, you want an abstraction that encompasses the general case. You say as much yourself when you mention "base class".

Comment: @Ed Guiness: Thanks for the comment, I've updated my question.

Comment: The technical term is [hypernym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy). I have added that tag.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think you should post Transaction as your answer. That was actually what I was going to answer.

Comment: @Bruno: Obviously you & I would be easier able to read each other's program code if that's what we both called this class. But the most important thing is the name should be meaningful to the guy that *writes* the code, since he's usually got most to do with it. Or I might just call it a **THINGY** and global rename every occurence later if I decided I didn't get on with that name after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect, you don't actually want a synonym, you want an abstraction that encompasses the general case.  You say as much yourself when you talk about a "base class".

So why not look at what is common in these three things?

Each of them is a communication of information about an order, between two or more parties. Each of them will have a date, a sender, an order reference, and one or more recipients.

Sounds awfully like we are talking about a letter.  Or more generally, a communication.  Or maybe correspondence.

As a programmer, I'd probably go for something like order-correspondence.  Then, when I realise that I also need a class for *receipt* I've got a ready-made base class.

On the other hand, given such a problem, I'd probably go back to the design board and have a good think about what data I have to deal with, and for what purposes, and hope that having a serious think about the design would lead me naturally to the identification of good entity names.

In other words, if the names aren't obvious, the design probably needs more thought.

Comment: You're implying that a good programming base should be clearly identifiable using readily-available words from standard English, but that's not at all the case. OP's class is almost certainly what he needs, and I bet he pretty much knows what kind of functionality & attributes it will have. He's just getting hung up on the name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will admit that some constructs, the minority, have no convenient English names, but I also submit that these few exceptions prove the general rule. Even a random collection of properties can be called a "bag" etc. We may have to agree to differ on this one.

Comment: As you will. Personally I think not only does software not automatically map to the real world - it often *conflicts* with our default ways of thinking. Which is one of the reasons why AI and computerised natural language processing haven't exactly got far despite all the efforts in recent years.

Answer (score 2):

Though we can see relations between these three, I doubt you'll find a satisfying synonym to encompass the meaning of all since, similarities aside, they actually *do* stand for quite different things.

The closest I could posit might be **receipt**, since each of these have the same property of being received by the person going through the order process.

So, in terms of programming a base class, this *could* make sense, but I guess we might need more information and a different location to discuss this aspect in much more detail.

Comment: I actually liked the word you gave in the comment above. 'Transaction', that somewhat describes it.

Comment: @Kevin: That wasn't me, but I can see how you might adopt the word in this context, but it does differ slightly from what you say you want, as nothing is really being _exchanged_ in all instances. Though in terms of conducting proceedings, you could get away with it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, can't see how I missed that. Thanks for your comment and answer.

Comment: Related: [Noun for “receive”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18351/5822)

Answer (score 1):

How about *[paper trail](http://www.wordnik.com/words/paper%20trail)*?

> the records left by a person or organization in the course of activities.

<sup>Wiktionary</sup>

Answer (score 1):

- **statement** sounds to me like the common concept to these, and it has a particular usage in the domain you seem to be covering (business accounting?)
- a good way to look for more general superclass names (in object oriented programming) which is a synonym of **hypernym** which RegDwight mentioned, is to look in a thesaurus (online or off). Even though a thesaurus is nominally for synonyms (nearby words on roughly the same semantic plane) they tend to give some generalizing terms (hypernyms) and more specific terms (hyponyms), too.
- another good source for such vocabulary is to ask the domain experts. You're probably developing for someone or a group that already has a lot of technical vocabulary about the domain, they will be more likely to have the word that you're looking for. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Your program should obviously match the business model of the process it's supposed to facilitate / record. So call the base class **SALE**.

It's still 'potentially' a sale even at the Quotation stage, and the business itself only cares about that stage if it leads to an actual sale anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about *procurement phase* or *procurement paperwork*?

Answer (score 0):

Though answered already, some may find that a relevant hypernym for their case is:

> Memoranda / Memorandum

the singular and plural forms.

Answer (score -1):

They all sound like documents to me. So, I would use *document*.

Comment: By that logic, "document" would be the base class for just about everything. I think Borland C++ Builder had "Object" as its lowest-level base class, but such things are really a bit too general for app-level programming.

Comment: That is true, but given that we don't know the biz domain, that was my best guess since those usually get genned as printable docs. OrderCorrespondence, maybe...but now we're off EL&U and over to SO.

There's always "Stuff" :)

Comment: I gotta be honest, I have in the past created classes called QWERTY, MYCLASS, ZZZ, etc. And eventually renamed them to something more meaningful after writing enough calling code to find out what they actually *do*.