# Noun for "send"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There is a [noun for "receive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18351/noun-for-receive): reception.

What about "send"? Is there a noun for this verb?

It's about sending SMS messages, so I wish to underline the outgoing nature of the message.

Comment: *Sendention*? Maybe we should stick with *transmission*.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have a context in mind? Depending on context, many words could fit your purpose. As Bib says, *transmission,* but also *shipment, mission, transfer, messaging, sending, despatch...*

Comment: **Not** *sending* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sending

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with bib. Transmission is probably the best comparison here. Transmission comes from the Latin noun [transmissio](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmissio#Latin), which comes from the Latin verb mitto (mittere) meaning I send (to send).

Comment: I ended up using "sending", which is also a noun, but the accepted answer is still correct.

Comment: There's a related post dealing with the meaning of *transmission* in various contexts and how it differs sometimes from *a message sent*. Please search previous posts.

Answer (score 4):

Possible nouns linked to send, are 'conveyance' or 'consignment'. One can, also, rather than 'send' the goods, 'consign' them.

And that of 'receive', in the case of goods is not 'reception' but 'receipt'. I find myself 'in receipt' of letters and goods, never in 'reception' of them.

I am however, from time to time in 'reception' of visitors.

So I think it's 'receipt' for goods, 'reception' for people.

Answer (score 3):

In some contexts, you can use "emission".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved with an explanation as to *why* and *in which contexts* you could use *emission*. I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on contributing to the site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on just what is being sent. A letter once sent becomes a *missive*, a word built  on the soundest of etymological foundations.

But if you prefer epistles over letters, we may have to fish from a different etymological lake.

Comment: Too smart for me :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered "[texting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/texting)" and "[text messaging](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/text%20messaging)" as possible alternative terms to "SMS sending?"